# "I told X my feelings" vs "I told X about my feelings"

Tags: word-difference

What's the difference between the two? Is one more grammatically correct than the other?

> Telling John my feelings wasn't the only thing that scared me that night.

> Telling John about my feelings wasn't the only thing that scared me that night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both grammatically correct. The first seems more soul-baringly honest; it assumes the speaker can actually put his/her feelings directly into words. The second implies the speaker can only describe those feelings by talking "about them". This is a subtle difference, so use whichever seems more appropriate.